# gMaps installation on ExpressionEngine3

Tags: ee3, google-maps

At the start I just want to say hi to everyone as I am new to this message board.

I got a problem with gmaps plugin bought from devot-ee, after installing gmaps plugin and gmaps field type this error occures on everypage at the very top:

> Notice Use of undefined constant GMAPS_FT_AUTHOR - assumed
>   'GMAPS_FT_AUTHOR' user/addons/gmaps_fieldtype/addon.setup.php, line 16
>   hide details
>
> Severity: E_NOTICE Notice Use of undefined constant
>   GMAPS_FT_AUTHOR_URL - assumed 'GMAPS_FT_AUTHOR_URL'
>   user/addons/gmaps_fieldtype/addon.setup.php, line 17 hide details
>
> Severity: E_NOTICE Warning Cannot modify header information - headers
>   already sent by (output started at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cork-comedy-festival/backstage/ee/legacy/core/Exceptions.php:112)
>   ee/legacy/core/Input.php, line 249 show details
>
> Severity: E_WARNING Warning Cannot modify header information - headers
>   already sent by (output started at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cork-comedy-festival/backstage/ee/legacy/core/Exceptions.php:112)
>   ee/legacy/core/Input.php, line 249 show details
>
> Severity: E_WARNING Warning Cannot modify header information - headers
>   already sent by (output started at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cork-comedy-festival/backstage/ee/legacy/core/Exceptions.php:112)
>   ee/legacy/core/Input.php, line 249 show details
>
> Severity: E_WARNING Warning Cannot modify header information - headers
>   already sent by (output started at
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/cork-comedy-festival/backstage/ee/legacy/core/Exceptions.php:112)
>   ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Boot/boot.common.php, line 463 show
>   details

If someone could advise me how to fix this error.

Kind Regards,
Remi.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution..
I have added These lines to config.php file in line 16

```
define('GMAPS_FT_AUTHOR', 'gmap');
define('GMAPS_FT_AUTHOR_URL', 'gmap');
```